# Connect to database running in local from application running inside docker container

Tags: java, database, windows, docker, docker-container

I am new to docker, attempting to connect oracle database running in local from an application running inside docker.

Getting below error:

**IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection**.

I browsed that we can pull oracle image and run in the docker container but I want to connect locally running database.

**Can someone please guide me how to connect oracle database running in `local windows machine` from `application inside docker container`.**

Code to get `SessionFactory` instance:

```
private SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
    if (sessionFactory == null) {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            // Hibernate settings equivalent to hibernate.cfg.xml's
            // properties
            System.out.println("SessionFactory getting called");
            Properties settings = new Properties();
            settings.put(Environment.DRIVER, "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            settings.put(Environment.URL, "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xxxxx");
            settings.put(Environment.USER, "xxxxx");
            settings.put(Environment.PASS, "xxxx");
            settings.put(Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect");
            settings.put(Environment.SHOW_SQL, "true");
            settings.put(Environment.CURRENT_SESSION_CONTEXT_CLASS, "thread");
            settings.put(Environment.C3P0_MIN_SIZE, 10);
            settings.put(Environment.C3P0_MAX_SIZE, 100);
            settings.put(Environment.C3P0_TIMEOUT, 300);
            configuration.setProperties(settings);
            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(SecretQuestionsEnity.class).addAnnotatedClass(CustomerEntity.class)
                    .addAnnotatedClass(AddressEntity.class).addAnnotatedClass(SecretAnswersEntity.class)
                    .addAnnotatedClass(BranchEntity.class).addAnnotatedClass(AccountEntity.class)
                    .addAnnotatedClass(CurrentACEntity.class).addAnnotatedClass(SavingsACEntity.class)
                    .addAnnotatedClass(TransactionEntity.class).addAnnotatedClass(PayeeEntity.class);
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

**Error :**

```
2020-07-24 16:32:09 WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 17002, SQLState: 08006
2020-07-24 16:32:10 ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are running an application inside docker container then the `localhost` refers to `container` not your local windows machine

```
settings.put(Environment.URL, "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xxxxx");
```

Either you can give your **windows machine IP address** instead of `localhost` in the URL string or you can read it from environment variable by [passing it](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file) in docker `run` command.

Comment: Hi Prathap ,   Thanks for your response  i replaced ip address instead of localhost in listner.ora and tnsname.ora.. it is working great . thanks much.